# Word Mover's Distance vs Cosine Similarity

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, semantics, cosine-similarity

I wonder which algorithm is the best for semantic similarity? Can anyone explain why?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Semantic similarity of what - words,, phrases, sentences, paragraphs, documents, other? And 'best' with respect to what end goal?

The original paper which defined 'Word Mover's Distance', "[From Word Embeddings To Document Distances](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v37/kusnerb15.pdf)", gave some examples of where WMD works well, and comparisons of its behavior against other similarity-calculations.

But, WMD is far more expensive to calculate, especially on longer texts. And as a method which uses every word's presence, regardless of ordering, it still isn't strong in cases where tiny grammatical changes – such as the addition of a 'not' in the right place – might completely reverse a text's meaning to human readers. (But then again, quick-and-simple comparisons like the cosine-similarity between two bag-of-words representations, or between two average-of-word-vectors representations, aren't strong there either.)